# How do I create color transparency layers in CS6?

Tags: color, layers, cs6, transparency

I have many times wanted to have transparent images layered on other transparencies as if they were laying on a light table. Is there an easier way to do this in CS6? [image]

Comment: Easier than what? Layer modes?

Comment: I'd say this is another Photoshop 101...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Blending Modes

In Illustrator you change the blending mode of objects using the Transparency panel, you can also change the blending mode of specific fills and strokes etc using the Appearance panel.

- [Illustrator Help / Transparency and blending modes](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html#about_blending_modes)

In Photoshop you change the blending mode using the Layers panel or using the Layer Style options.

- [Photoshop Help / Blending modes](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html)

Example of the "Soft Light" Blending mode:

[image: Soft Light Blending Mode]

And the "Multiply" Blending mode:

[image: Multiply Blending Mode]

Probably the closest to your example image is using "Color Burn" at 70% opacity:

[image: Color Burn Blending Mode]

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help